# How to set own image for a cursor

Tags: eclipse-rap

If I set the cursor for a Label in a css-file as shown below it works as expected. The cursor is a "wait-cursor" if it is moved over the Label

```
Label.mylabel:hover {
    cursor: wait;
}
```

As it is described in the RWT-Theming-Reference the following should also be possible

```
Label.mylabel:hover {
    cursor: url( resources/cursor.gif );
}
```

But I can not see my cursor.
How can I set an own image for a cursor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out that there is a [bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=472085) in RAP that prevents custom cursors from being rendered. I'll provided a [fix](https://git.eclipse.org/r/#/c/51519/) that will likely be included in the 3.0.1 release.

**Update:** the fix is merged and will be available in 3.1 M1 and 3.0.1.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
label.mylabel:hover {
    cursor:url("resources/cursor.gif"), auto;
}
```

Make sure that your are providing correct url for image.

Comment: This does not work on my system, I use RAP 3.0.0. The url to the image is correct; if not, I see a CSSException at startup.